# How can I get a Regigigas in Pokemon Ranger Shadows of Almia?

Tags: pokemon-ranger

I have all the Regis but I don't know where he is. Where can I find Regigigas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this post on [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/944533-pokemon-ranger-shadows-of-almia/answers/14926-okay-where-is-the-regigigas-thing), the answer says

> You have to complete the other browser entrees, then talk to Barlow to learn of a new Pokemon, after that go to Ranger Union to receive more detail. It is in a vortex in the center of the room in Hippowdown Temple with the arrows that move you in a direction. Go there to place the Regis on the pedestals and prepare for possibly the toughest single battle in the game